# When I try to upgrade my maven project in eclipse it throws error

Tags: eclipse, maven, project

Im new to eclipse and maven and trying to create a new project but when i try to upgrade my maven project it throws this error: : Unable to configure "project name", plugin: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender. I searced for everything but cannot find a usefull help for this problem

here's my `web.xml`, when I change the code in `web-app` tag then it throws error

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HotlineManagerV2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>HotlineManagerV2.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jettison.JettisonFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HotlineManagerV2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Show (e.g. your `pom.xml`) and explain (e.g., what exactly did you mean by _upgrade_ here?) everything that is necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I found out my problem was with the Dynamic Web Module's version number, it was wrong